# Installing Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Vista

Tags: 12.10, windows-vista

During repartitioning there was an error and after sending the error report my screen went black. Back in Vista and everything seems OK but not sure what happened or how to proceed with a second attempt. I'm a total noob here so any info appreciated. Explain it to me like I'm five.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I installed 12.10 alongside windows 7 for a freind, i think the same method should work for vista.

first install wubi for 12.10 on the site: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer.

install it on windows, run it and install your ubuntu from it. just follow the install wizard and it will ask for reboot of your system when through .

The rebot automatically opens ubuntu and finalise setup.
then it'll restart, asking you normally, to choose which os to boot with.